# System.TypeInitializationException when setting parameters into a Configuration Section (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, app-config

I have a WPF app that reads data from my App.Config file.
App.Config looks like:

```
<configuration>
[...]
  <MySection>
    <application>
      <general displayConsole="true"/>
     <!-- <general displayDebug="false"/> -->
    </application>
  </MySection>
</configuration>
```

I access the section with this class:

```
   public class ApplicationSetting : AbstractSetting
    {
        private const string SECTION_GROUP = "MySection";
        private const string SECTION_APPLICATION = "application";

        [ConfigurationProperty("general", IsRequired = true)]
        public GeneralElement General { get { return (GeneralElement)this["general"]; } set { this["general"] = value; } }

        public static ApplicationSetting Load()
        {
            return (ApplicationSetting)Configuration.GetSection(SECTION_GROUP + "/" + SECTION_APPLICATION);
        }
    }

    public class GeneralElement : ConfigurationElement
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("displayConsole", IsRequired = true)]
        public bool DisplayConsole { get { return (bool)this["displayConsole"]; } set { this["displayConsole"] = value; } }
/*
        [ConfigurationProperty("displayDebug", IsRequired = true)]
        public bool DisplayDebug { get { return (bool)this["displayDebug"]; } set { this["displayDebug"] = value; } }*/
    }
```

Now if I want to add a second parameter to this app and un-comment the commented line, I get the following exception:

> 'System.TypeInitializationException' into
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll

Why so? I suspecct a shameful XML issue?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It WAS indeed a shameful XML issue as anticipated.
In case anyone ever cares, the correct syntax was:

```
  <valeoConfigs>
    <application>
      <general displayConsole="true"  displayDebug="false"/>
    </application>
  </valeoConfigs>
```